# sudo vim crontab vs sudo crontab e - when to use

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron, sudo

I am trying to get to grip with cron jobs on ubuntu.

I am not sure of the difference between

```
sudo crontab -e
```

and

```
sudo vim /etc/crontab
```

I assume they both create cron jobs which run under root?

However they give me different files.

`sudo vim /etc/crontab`

gives me /etc/crontab I think, which is the system wide cron responsible for run-parts and execution of cron.daily etc.

I assume therefore that

`sudo crontab -e`

creates a personal crontab under /var/spool/cron/crontabs (as per any other user crontab)?  But sudo makes it operate under root privileges and associates the crontab to the root user?

Is this correct?

i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When editing `/etc/crontab` or creating a file under `/etc/cron.d`, `/etc/cron.daily` etc. you are free to choose the user which should run the command. These files should be editable by root only. The file format is:

```
* * * * * USER COMMAND
```

When you use the `crontab -e` command you can't specify the user which runs the command. It is the user which executes `crontab -e`. The syntax is simply:

```
* * * * * COMMAND
```

IMHO it makes no sense to use `crontab -e` as root. Please check [`man 1 crontab`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/crontab). It gives a proper explanation.

Comment: sudo crontab -e would simply place a crontab for root user under /var/spool/....and execute as root...correct?  Thanks

Comment: Yes this is correct. However, it makes no sense for me. `root` is supposed  to edit `/etc/crontab` and friends, and mostly a cronjob *don't* even need to run as `root`.

Comment: Actually, root can edit anyone's personal crontab - using `-u` option.